# Informatica - failing due to unique constraint violation for the primary key column

Tags: informatica-powercenter

A sequence generator transformation is used to generate the primary key column  which generates this key in sequential order for the incoming records and stores the maximum key value used in each session at the end of the session in the informatica repository. The issue is likely to occur when two or more workflows start running with  the same key value stored in the repository  and the workflow with more number of records completed first. In this case the maximum value updated by the first workflow gets updated with the lesser value (which is the maximum value of the second workflow) when the workflow with less number of records completes. Because of this in the next ODS run, the first workflow gets a value for sequence generator which is already used in the previous run and thus causes unique constraint violation.

Comment: Do you have two workflows that use a single reusable sequence generator transformation?

Comment: And the question is? Hint, look through your post and work out where you'd put  a question mark